# How can I route to login if canLoad or canActivate fails, without routing in AuthGuard itself?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngrx, auth-guard

So, this is what my AuthGuard looks like:

```
canLoad(route: Route) {
    return this.store.select(fromRoot.getIsAuth).pipe(take(1));
}
```

I check Authentication information from app.component and simply return an Observable boolean.

I don't want to subscribe to this to reroute, I don't want to use router.navigate inside AuthGuard so I want to keep it a simple Guard.

Is there a way to reroute inside routing-module, that simply routes to an alternate path if AuthGuard returns false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you have to do the navigation in the guard. No way to configure the router to do what you want. But you don't need to subscribe. You can use tap to do the navigation.

```
canLoad(route: Route) {
    return this.store.select(fromRoot.getIsAuth)
        .pipe(
            take(1),
            tap(loggedIn => {
                if (!loggedIn) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
            })
        );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it just keeps looping without any navigating. Added a console.log before navigate and gave 600 messages but no navigating.

Comment: It's hard to say what your problem is without more information. I suspect that you have the canLoad guard also applied to the login route. This would explain why it loops so many times.

Comment: Don't have any other AuthGuard on any other path, path: '' activates AuthGuard, which should redirect to path: '/login' which doesn't have CanActivate or anything. It just loops inside path: ''.

Comment: can you add your router configuration to your question?

Comment: Okay I fixed it, it wasn't a guard but order of my routes was causing a loop, your solution works, thank you!

Comment: There is an issue open to change this behavior - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28306 - but it was rejected because `We aren't actually adding this feature for CanLoad guards since this type of guard is really completely separate from the others (probably shouldn't have been called a Guard actually). But the other suggestions are great.`

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; If you navigate directly inside `OnLoad` you'll get a NavigationCancel event with a message about a mismatched ID (and I HATE that error!). You can avoid it like this :

```
this.routerEvents.navigationCancel$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() =>
{           
      this.router.navigateByUrl(result); 
});

return false;
```

---

I'm not sure exactly when most people are using `canLoad` vs. `canActivate` but my specific case (and solution) is as follows:

- I have a login dialog that gets displayed from inside my `AuthGuard` service. The `AuthGuard` shows the dialog but does not return true/false until the user has tried to log in.
- The `AuthGuard` service returns `UrlTree` if the login fails and the user needs to be redirected to a particular page (such as support page)
- My '/account` route is lazy loaded and may take a couple seconds to load
- I want the login dialog to appear *instantly* when the user clicks 'Account' hence adding `CanLoad`
- Therefore what I did was to put the same logic into my `canLoad` handler. This means the `canLoad` will also show a dialog box if it gets hit first.
- I left my `canActivate` guard to run the exact same logic (don't worry - you won't ever see two dialogs)

For this case I found it easiest to do the following in `canLoad`:

```
canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[])
   {
       const currentNavigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
       const isInitialNavigation = !currentNavigation.previousNavigation;

       if (isInitialNavigation)
       {
           return true;   // always allow load for first navigation (avoids other complications)
       }
       else {

           // returns Observable<boolean | UrlTree> 
           return showLoginDialog().pipe(map(result => {

               if (typeof result === 'boolean') {
                  return result;
               }
               else {
                     // we have a URL tree
                    // wait for the expected NavigationCancel event and then navigate
                    this.routerEvents.navigationCancel$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() =>
                    {           
                       this.router.navigateByUrl(result); 
                    });
                   return false;
                }
           });;    
       }
}
```

I also have a root provided `RouterEvents` service where I define

```
  navigationCancel$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter((e): e is NavigationCancel => e instanceof NavigationCancel));
```

Note: watch out if you choose not to include the `isInitialNavigation` check. If your redirect is trying to redirect to the homepage then it won't work because the router thinks you're already there. You can solve this with a `/redirect_home` route that just redirects to homepage - or change the `onSameURLNavigation` setting.